# Using GTM to pull form submission data

Tags: javascript

I hope somebody can help me here.

Little background.

I have a website I built using squarespace. I have a form that people will submit with their info when they want a quote such as first name/lastname/email/phone/address etc. I want to pull this data and send it to facebook via GTM using some javascript.

Inside GTM, I created several variables to target this form submission data. I'm able to successfully retrieve the First Name + Last Name, but no other variables are returning, all say Undefined.

I can retrieve the first/last name using `return document.getElementsByName` -- If I right click my form and Inspect, I can see the First Name is as follows:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" autocomplete="given-name" class="MUomU4fr3iSZrhBNTmN0 exokPtqDa3qLy42TT3gA" id="name-yui_3_17_2_1_1553888888520_3744-fname-field" name="fname" type="text" value="">
```

Here is the GTM variable I created to target the first name:

```
function(){
    return document.getElementsByName("fname")[0] ? document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value : "";
}
```

This works perfectly.

However, the email/phone/address don't have a specified "name" but they do have unique "ID". Here is what it shows when I right click->inspect for the email:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" autocomplete="false" class="MUomU4fr3iSZrhBNTmN0 exokPtqDa3qLy42TT3gA" id="email-yui_3_17_2_1_1553888888520_3745-field" placeholder="" type="email" value="">
```

Here is the variable I used to target the data that didn't have a unique "Name". I used `return document.getElementById`

```
function(){
    return document.getElementById("email-yui_3_17_2_1_1553888888520_3745")[0] ? document.getElementById("email-yui_3_17_2_1_1553888888520_3745")[0].value : "";
}
```

Instead of using the name, i tried using ID but returns undefined.

Comment: `getElementById()` returns a single element, not a collection. You can't index it with `[0]`. Just return the value itself.